# Sort NSFetchRequest by a predicate

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I have a SQLite-backed core data storage and would like to fetch a list of managed objects using `NSFetchRequest`. I want said list to be sorted by a boolean value that can be easily calculated at the database level. I know this because it’s possible to formulate the same conditions using an `NSPredicate`, which would look as follows:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid = %@", currentUID]
```

Sadly, there seems to be no way to formulate a condition like this using an `NSSortDescriptor`. How do I best go about this? Do I fetch two lists, one with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid = %@", currentUID]
```

and one with

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uid != %@", currentUID]
```

and combine them later on? Can I then still elegantly use a `NSFetchedResultsController`?
Or should I fetch all items and sort them later in code? Or is there anything I’ve missed.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array (even if it contains only a single element) of `NSSortDescriptors` to sort the result as desired.

You use `setSortDescriptors:` to set them.

The fetch can handle both predicates and sorting at the same time.

Comment: It’s not that I don’t know how to set multiple `NSSortDescriptor`s. Rather, my question was, in a nutshell: how do I configure my `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by an expression instead of a static field name?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Ah, sorry. You can't, really. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927762/how-to-sort-based-on-a-calculated-value-from-multiple-core-data-attributes And as the quote from the docs implicates, you probably shouldn't, either.

Answer (score -1):

What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

A predicate is used to select which objects should be returned in a set of results.  This is determined by evaluating the predicate against each object to see if the predicate evaluates to `YES` or `NO` (a binary value, or one of 2 possible values).  If it evaluates to `YES`, then the object is included.  If it evaluates to `NO`, then the object is excluded.  There is no middle ground.

By contrast, a sort descriptor evaluates to `less than`, `equal`, or `greater than`.  In other words, it is a *ternary* value (it can be one of *3* things).  There is no way to express a ternary value with a predicate (since a predicate is binary), and so using a predicate as a sort descriptor makes absolutely no sense.  The API doesn't allow it, because *logic* doesn't allow it.

So the real question is:  what are you trying to do?  Why do you think you need a predicate in your sort descriptors?

Comment: Ok, I understand where you’re coming from and see that my description was a bit confusing. I am not trying to USE predicates to sort my results, I just mentioned them because they provide the functionality to calculate the value that I want to sort my results by. In other words, all the results where my predicate matches should come before the results where the predicate does not match; the boolean returned by the predicate for a single object should be used by the sort descriptor to compare it to the other object (thus yielding your ternary result). I hope this makes things clearer.