# How to sort based on a calculated value from multiple Core Data attributes

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I'm trying to create a sort descriptor, for a core data fetch request, that will fetch objects that are ordered by a calculated value (e.g., the sum of two or more attributes). Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties
>   (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory
>   yourself). ... To
>   summarize, though, if you execute a fetch directly, you should
>   typically not add Objective-C-based predicates or sort descriptors to
>   the fetch request. Instead you should apply these to the results of
>   the fetch.

So sorting by a calculated value seems not to be possible. You have to pre-calculate the sorting value and store it as (non-transient) attribute in your objects.